# C# consecutive using-statements

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

I have couple of comboboxes in my project. And their content is changing a lot. So I put their content in my database. Now, I wrote a code like below for retrieving their data but I wonder, is this 'usings' working like my approach or doesn't matter at all? My main question is; is this a healthy way to use objects like this?

```
DataTable results;
using (results = myDataInteractionClass.SelectDB())
{
    // fill table objects to combobox
}

using (results = myDataInteractionClass.SelectAnotherDB())
{
    // fill this new table's objects to combobox
}

using (results = myDataInteractionClass.SelectThirdDB())
{
    // so goes on like this.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. You should always narrow down the scope as much as possible, so having three `using`s here is good (opposed to one `using` around the entire block).

One suggestion though: to prevent misuse of `dataTable` between or after the `using`, I would suggest to create the variable inside the `using`:

```
using (/*so here*/ DataTable results = myDataInteractionClass.SelectDB())
{
    // fill table objects to combobox
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer & advice. I pre-defined the datatable because I think like "maybe if I use one datatable definition at first, I can make profit of device's stack RAM area & performance.". It's not that necessary & readability is more important in this situation then?

Answer (score 1):

As I guess your only goal is to read values from table and fill them in combobox, consider using DataReader Insted of DataTable it is lightweight compared to DataTable. And yes Patrick's suggestion is appropriate. I normally use var with using statement.

Comment: oh, ok. that makes more sense to make profit of performance rather than my method. thanks.

Comment: @mimozz usually, if an answer solves your problem or gives useful information, you upvote it to appreciate the effort.